# Lua/Corona Pause Button working outside the button

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Anybody have any ideas as to why my pause button won't work?... If you click anywhere on the screen it pauses when it should be confided to just the button.

code:

```
function pauseIt(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        if paused == false then
            audio.play(sound_pause)
             physics.pause()
             paused = true
        elseif paused == true then

             physics.start()
             audio.play(sound_pause)
             paused = false
        end
   end
end

paused = false
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", pauseIt)



   pause = display.newImage( screenGroup, "pause.png" )
    pause.x = _W * 0.12
    pause.y = _H * 0.06
    pause.xScale = 0.2
    pause.yScale = 0.2
    pause.touch = pauseIt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `pause.touch = pauseIt` which will cause `pauseIt(event)` to be called when button touched, this is good. But you also have a general event handler for whole scene after you do `Runtime:addEventListener("touch", pauseIt)`. Remove that one.

You also need to make button listen for tap event:

```
pause:addEventListener("tap", pauseIt)
```

The corona docs are excellent (for example http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/application-programming-guide-tutorial-introduction#Basic_Interactivity).

Comment: I took it out but now there is nothing happening at all when the button is clicked

Comment: @user3178851 I edited because you also need the make the button listen for events, let me know if this edit fixes issue or, for benefit of others, what ended up fixing the problem.